# computation time in flutter with firebase as backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, dart, backend

**I had a general question, suppose I have 10 million query's in my backend that is firebase, and a user wants to search one of them, how much time will it generally take to display the result.**

Comment: Please edit the question to show the specific code you are working with.  Also be clear about what product you're working with.  Firebase is a platform with over a dozen products, including two databases.

Comment: i have mentioned in the question itself, that's its a general question, and whatever data base you may think off, you can answer with respect to that itself.

Comment: Thai can't be addressed generally. There needs to be a specific case, as different backend products have different performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend. Are you doing heavy calculations in the backend or just lite, but anyway you can use `async` `await` rather than guessing how much time the backend response would take (also don't forget about the user connection speed) with `async` `await` you can wait for the response while showing the splash screen without giving it any fixed time.

```
Future myFunc() async {
showLoadingScreen();
await response();
showData();
}
```

Comment: but wont it look bad, if async,await  took 10 or more seconds, and the user is just watching splash screen for so long.

Comment: Yeah it will look bad, no one want to spend his/her time looking at loading screen  but showing an error or an empty data would be worse. You can do something while the data is loading as long as you are using await you can handle what would happened while the server is calculating the response but at the end it will depend on the backend. In some case the problem should be fixed in the frontend but in this case it should be solved from the backend and doing some optimization.